# Is there a quick way to add gettext() calls to strings in PyDev?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, gettext

Is there a quick way to add a `gettext()` call to a literal string in the PyDev editor running under Eclipse? I.e. when I place the cursor on any literal `'string'` in a Python file, I want to turn this into `_('string')` with a single keypress. Can I use macros or something like that to add such functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to do that with some simple Python scripting inside PyDev.

Take a look at: http://pydev.org/manual_articles_scripting.html (you can use https://github.com/aptana/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev.jython/jysrc/pyedit_import_to_string.py as an example).

For the text selection, the PySelection implementation may be found at: https://github.com/aptana/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev.core/src/org/python/pydev/core/docutils/PySelection.java (so, you can see how getSelectedText and work your own version to get the text you want).

Comment: Thanks, I'll experiment a bit with PyDev scripting then. The tutorial you referenced recommends creating a Jython project for that purpose. Does it mean I need to install Jython first? I haven't used Jython and PyDev scripting before.

Comment: You don't really need to install Jython (the scripting will always use the internal jython, so, you don't really need to have Jython -- you can just use a regular Python project).

Comment: Ok, understood. I'll try to work through the example you mentinoed. It's pretty complicated actually, so I'll postpone it to later this week and will see how far I can get. As far as I understand, there are actually three scripts involved in this example: `assign_params_to_attributes_action`, `assign_params_to_attributes_assist` and `pyedit_assign_params_to_attributes`, the latter binds the action to both Ctrl+1 ("additional assist") and Ctrl+2 ("offline action"). By setting `WAIT_FOR_ENTER` to `False` I would be able to trigger the action with the key combination "Ctrl+2 g" for example.

Comment: I'm sorry about that (seems I had copied the wrong link, that one was really complicated, not the one I wanted to copy), so, just edited to give you the link I meant to give before (which should be simple).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I understand PyDev scripting now and was able to create a solution with these pointers (I have posted my script as an additional answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little PyDev script that I was able to create with the hints given by Fabio. If you press Ctrl+2,t then the literal string at the cursor position will be surrounded with a gettext call. I'm not sure whether I'm using the Java API as expected, but it works for me. If you have ideas for improvement, please comment.

```
if cmd == 'onCreateActions':
    from org.eclipse.jface.action import Action
    from org.python.pydev.core import IPythonPartitions
    from org.python.pydev.core.docutils import ParsingUtils, PySelection

    class AddGettext(Action):
        """Add gettext call around literal string at cursor position."""

        GETTEXT = '_'

        def run(self):
            sel = PySelection(editor)
            doc = sel.getDoc()
            pos = sel.getAbsoluteCursorOffset()
            ctype = ParsingUtils.getContentType(doc, pos)
            if ctype == IPythonPartitions.PY_SINGLELINE_STRING1:
                char, multi = "'", False
            elif ctype == IPythonPartitions.PY_SINGLELINE_STRING2:
                char, multi = '"', False
            elif ctype == IPythonPartitions.PY_MULTILINE_STRING1:
                char, multi = "'", True
            elif ctype == IPythonPartitions.PY_MULTILINE_STRING2:
                char, multi = '"', True
            else:
                char = None
            if char:
                par = ParsingUtils.create(doc)
                if multi:
                    start = par.findPreviousMulti(pos, char)
                    end = par.findNextMulti(pos, char)
                else:
                    start = par.findPreviousSingle(pos, char)
                    end = par.findNextSingle(pos, char)
                doc.replace(end + 1, 0, ')')
                doc.replace(start, 0, self.GETTEXT + '(')

    ACTIVATION_STRING = 't'
    WAIT_FOR_ENTER = False

    editor.addOfflineActionListener(
        ACTIVATION_STRING, AddGettext(), 'Add gettext call', WAIT_FOR_ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/):

```
  :map gt ca'_(<esc>pa)<esc>
```

Note that this only works with single-quoted strings, it does not recognize when you use double quotes or multi-line strings.